# How the quotients of central series forms a Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a group. Then the subgroups of the central series are $\gamma_1(G)=G$, $\gamma_2(G)=[\gamma_1(G),G],..., \gamma_n(G)=[\gamma_{n-1}(G),G]$. Then in the reference paper given below it is given that the direct sum $\bigoplus_{n\geq1}\frac{\gamma_n(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)}$ forms a Lie algebra over $\mathbb{Z}$. (http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/GMJ/vol9/v9n4-9.pdf).

My first question is that if the notion of Lie algebra is defined over some field, then how we can use $\mathbb{Z}$ (set of integers)?

Kindly explain how this direct sum can become a Lie algebra. In the reference paper above it is given that the commutator map $\gamma_n \times \gamma_m\rightarrow \gamma_{m+n}$ is given by $(x,y)\longmapsto [x,y]$ but I can't understand this mapping.

One more thing: it is given that there is a canonical map from $G_{ab}$ to $\bigoplus_{n\geq1}\frac{\gamma_n(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)}$ inducing a surjective homomorphism from $L(G_{ab})$ to $\bigoplus_{n\geq1}\frac{\gamma_n(G)}{\gamma_{n+1}(G)}$, where $L(G_{ab})$ is the free Lie algebra over $G_{ab}$. How we can define this when $\gamma_2$ is present in the first summand of the direct sum?

I know these are very silly questions but I tried a lot to understand this but was not able to understand. Please help me out to know about this as I am a newcomer to the field of Lie algebras.

Comment: One can all a "Lie algebra" over $\Bbb Z$ a *Lie ring*.

Comment: These are not silly questions.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown dear sir, can you give any reference regarding this.

Comment: @JDZ sorry for writing that, but I thought at such platform a question from some text is not good thats why I wrote.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Lie_ring @MANISHANKARPANDEY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re **first question**: Although very often Lie algebras are defined over fields, one can just extend the definition to any (e.g.) commutative ring $R$:

> A *Lie algebra over $R$* is an $R$-module $L$ with a Lie bracket $[\cdot, \cdot]: L \times L \rightarrow L$ which is bilinear, alternating ($[x,x]=0$ for all $x\in L$) and satisfies  the Jacobi identity.

E.g. Bourbaki only restricts to $R$ being a field after paragraph 3 in the first chapter of their *Lie Groups and Lie Algebras* book. Also, Lie algebras over the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ are quite common in the theory of $p$-adic analytic groups (Lazard etc.). As mentioned in a comment, sometimes this more general object is called a "Lie ring". Of course one has to be careful about what "standard" results still hold true for this more general definition.

Re **second question**: First of all, I take it that for elements $x,y \in G$, the (group) commutator $[x,y]$ is defined as $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ (sometimes one defines it as $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$; insignificant changes apply).

Now let's check the above definition.

A. $\bigoplus \gamma_n(G)/\gamma_{n+1}(G)$ is a $\mathbb Z$-module. Clear, because every summand, being an abelian group, is a $\mathbb Z$-module (write the group operation additively as $\bar x +\bar y := \overline{xy}$).

B. Defining the Lie bracket: First, let's define the Lie bracket on a pair of homogeneous elements (i.e. elements which are contained in one of the summands). This is done as you say: if $\bar x \in \gamma_m(G)/\gamma_{m+1}(G), \bar y \in \gamma_n(G)/\gamma_{n+1}(G)$, then we define the Lie bracket $[x,y]$ as the residue class, in $\gamma_{m+n}(G)/\gamma_{m+n+1}(G)$, of the group commutator $[x,y]$. One checks that this is well-defined, $\mathbb Z$-bilinear, alternating, and satisfies the Jacobi identity.

Now, since every element of the direct sum is a finite sum of homogeneous elements, there is only one way to extend the definition bilinearly to all elements, namely

$$[\sum \bar x_i, \sum \bar y_j] = \sum_{i,j} [\bar x_i, \bar y_j]$$

($\bar x_i \in \gamma_i(G)/\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ etc.) and this is easily checked to still be alternating and satisfy the Jacobi identity.

Re **third question**: The abelianisation $G_{ab}:= G/[G,G]$ literally is $\gamma_1(G)/\gamma_2(G)$, the first summand in the direct sum, so the "canonical map" is indeed just the inclusion of that first summand into the entire sum. That this induces (or: "lifts to") a homomorphism from the free Lie algebra $L(G_{ab})$ to the sum is part of the universal property of a free object (or whatever definition of free Lie algebra you use, it should follow immediately from that). That it is *surjective* comes from the fact that additively, the direct sum is generated by all iterated group commutators $[g_1,[g_2,[g_3, .... ]]]$, and these are in the image of the free Lie algebra $L(G_{ab})$. Notice that for example there are generators $h$ of $\gamma_{2}(G)/\gamma_3(G)$ for which there are $x,y \in G$ such that $[x,y] + \gamma_3(G) = h$, and if $x_{ab}, y_{ab} \in G_{ab}$ are the respective residue classes in $G_{ab}$, then in $L(G_{ab})$ there is the element $[x_{ab},y_{ab}]_{L(G_{ab})}$ which via the univeral homomorphism gets mapped to $h$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can understand every part easily but in the second part, you wrote that  ``since every element of the direct sum is a finite sum of homogeneous elements", why finite sum? Please explain this.

Comment: That's part of the definition of a direct sum. An arbitrary element of $\bigoplus_{i \in I} A_i$ ($I$ any index set, $A_i$, say, abelian groups) is of the form $\sum_{i \in F} a_i$ for a finite subset $F \subseteq I$, and $a_i \in A_i$. Or, if you view the direct sum as subset of the direct product $\prod_i A_i$, then it consists of those elements where only finitely many coordinates $a_i \in A_i$ are non-zero. (And it is the (finite) sum of the $(0,...,0,a_i,0,...,0)$ for those (finitely many) $i$.)

Comment: @Toresten Thanks for your answer.